# Unable to retrieve Quote templates and Products information in salesforce developer sandbox

Tags: apex, soql, community, quote-template, zuora

We are installed Zuora in our organisation. There are two applications called Z-force quotes & Z-force 360 packages.When to try to create a quote in developer sandbox.I unable to retrieve Quote templates via lookup fields in sfdc. And when i try to select any products or rate plans available with in my organisation it shows empty.Please why this is happening both Z-force quotes & Z-force 360 packages are already installed with in the sfdc

For reference:
[image]

[image]